# react.js infinite loop for history back

Tags: reactjs, next.js

```js
import React from 'react';
import Router from 'next/router';

interface RedirectProps {
  to: string
}

class Redirect extends React.Component<RedirectProps> {
  componentDidMount() {
    Router.push(this.props.to)
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>redirect...</div>
    );
  }
}

export default Redirect;
```

```js
// signin page
if(this.props.store.isSignin) {
  return <Redirect to='/'/>
}
```

signin page used Router.push() function.

so /signin -> /, if go back / -> /signin -> /, infinite loop

how to escape?

Comment: I don't get how you are routed from `/` back to `/signin`, that isn't obvious from your example code.

Comment: @James just back button. just like excute history.back();

Comment: so that's a manual interaction, are you saying when you click the back button your app then goes into an infinite loop and doesn't stop redirecting?

Comment: So if you're signed in then you cannot go back to /signin which seems like a reasonable behaviour. What's the problem then?

Comment: @YM because /signout same reason. /signout -> / -> back -> /signout -> / infinite loop.

Comment: @James all right

Comment: Your `/` route must also have some kind of redirect, or you're not pushing what you meant to onto the Router stack. Either way, you should share more of your code if you want help.

Comment: You should remove authentication from store `this.props.store.isSignin` , it is working as the way it should but since you are not removing authentication from store it is behaving like this.